# Qual è il significato di "acchiappino" a Roma?

Tags: word-meaning, regional, nouns, cinema

In una scena del film *Italy in a day* appare un ragazzo che dice:

> Il mio lavoro è quello di fare **l'acchiappino**. Lavoro a Campo di Fiori, in una delle piazze più storiche di Roma.

Qual è il significato di "acchiappino" in questo contesto? Le definizioni che ho trovato nei dizionari fanno riferimento a un gioco infantile, ma una ricerca su Google riporta molte offerte di lavoro come acchiappino a Roma. Da quello che si vede nel film sembra qualcuno il cui compito è convincere i turisti di entrare nei ristoranti. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da come mi dice un collega romano, per ***acchiappino*** si intende una persona che pubblicizza un locale tramite volantinaggio (ecco il riferimento alle offerte di lavoro che hai trovato su internet) oppure un personaggio che si trova davanti ad un locale (tipo ristorante, pizzeria, etc) e invita i passanti ad entrare.

Il senso è una persona che cerca di "*acchiappare*" clienti per il locale per cui lavora.

Dalle mie parti verrebbe indicato anche come "***buttadentro***", cioè colui che è addetto a procacciare i clienti per un locale pubblico (spec. una discoteca o un locale notturno) e il cui opposto ***buttafuori*** indica una persona dedicata alla selezione della clientela e in generale alla sicurezza del locale.

Comment: “Buttadentro” è familiare anche a me che sono di Roma, mentre “acchiappino” mi mancava. Quali sono le “tue parti”, per completezza? (E puoi fare più caso agli accenti, per piacere?)

Comment: La mia zona è Savona, e scusa per gli accenti... ho una tastiera inglese ;-) A parte gli scherzi, farò più attenzione.

Comment: Curiosamente, [*buttafuori*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_133.jpg) appare nel supplemento del 2009 al GDLI, ma non si trovano né *buttadentro* né *acchiappino* con questo significato.